# Blog post and photos stop indexing from Google search

Tags: blogger

How to stop my blog post and photos indexing to google search. I want to remove my blog post and picture from Google search....Which method I use for it robot.text or No index method .

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. Go to your blogger dashboard. Click **Settings**. Under heading Basic, you will find a preference **Privacy**.
Set both the options to **No** and you are good to go. Your posts and images, no data will be listed on Google.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to delete all pages from index then use method as Gourav has said but if you want to noindex only few pages or posts like I have done on [hosterpak](https://hosterpak.com) website then add a wordpress plugin present on this link and you are ready to go, also go to Google web master tools and deindex from there too will help you to deindex the old pages faster then install this plugin. thanks.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-noindex-nofollow-tool-ii/